# Summation of Exponential function with mod from negative infinity to infinity

Tags: summation, exponential-function, exponential-sum

Can someone explain how this is true:-

$$ \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|k|} = -1 + \sum_{k = -\infty}^{0} e^{-|k|} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-|k|} $$

I cannot understand why the negative 1 comes in the end of the expression.

Comment: Or replace the first term $1$ by $-1$, which cancels the double counting of $k=0$. Yes. That's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

In general
$$\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} f(k) = \sum_{k = - \infty}^{-1} f(k) + f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)$$
and by setting $k$ to $-k$ in the first summation it reduces to
$$\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} f(k) = f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f(k) + f(-k)).$$
If the summation is to begin with $k=0$ then:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} f(k) &= f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f(k) + f(-k)) + (f(0) + f(-0)) - (f(0) + f(-0)) \\
&= - f(-0) + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (f(k) + f(-k)) \\
&= - f(0) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f(k) + f(-k)).
\end{align}

In the case of $f(k) = e^{-|k|}$ then 
$$\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{-|k|} = e^{-|0|} + 2 \, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-|k|} = 1 + 2 \, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-|k|}.$$

Now, if the summation is to start at $k=0$ then
$$\sum_{k = - \infty}^{\infty} e^{-|k|} =  -1 + 2 \, \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-|k|}.$$

Comment: There seems to be a 2 missing in the second step which should be multiplied to the summation.